# How can I add to a list in python by user input

Tags: python-2.7

I want to add to a list by user inputs. Here's my code:

```
list = []  
list.append = int(input())
print(list)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *What* exactly is your problem? What is happening when you run this code? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: list.append = int(input())        
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only. This is the error I'm confused about. I expecting to be able to add to the list by user input but I think either the code im using is wrong or  I dont understand fully what I should write. Okay I think I understand what is going on. I cant add a list  by user input cause .append is READ ONLY. So now  I need to figure out how to add to the list another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to set the "append" attribute of the list to the new value. `list.append` is the append attribute, which is read-only and can't be changed with `list.append = newValue` (explication of your error), while `list.append()` is the **method** which is actually what appends to your list.

```
list.append = int(input())
```

should be replaced with

```
list.append(int(input()))
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me .